# NoSql query results in The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that... exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a Core 6 application and to query data from Cosmos DB, and have written the following LINQ query upon the Entity Framework database context object:

```cs
var assets = _context.Assets
     .SelectMany(asset => asset.Cards
         .Where(card => card.CardType == "dummy"))
     .Select(a => a.Asset)
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

I am trying to fetch all Asset objects, that have a Card child object with CardType property set to "dummy". When I try to run the application and execute the code, the following exception is thrown:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DbAsset>()
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: d => EF.Property<ICollection<DbCard>>(d, "Cards")
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(o => o.CardType == "dummy"), 
        resultSelector: (d, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<DbAsset, DbCard>(
            Outer = d, 
            Inner = c
        ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I followed the documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/linq-to-sql and used Nesting, example 3 as a base reference to make the selection of Cards I require. I'm then trying to fetch their parent Assets in a Distinct and aggregate them into a list.

The database is several gigabytes and client evaluation would severely impact the performance of this application. I'm sure there is a better option, server side, but don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: _"from a NoSQL database"_ - which one exactly? Please add corresponding tag.

Comment: Added in description and tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking many resources regarding the subject, I've come to the conclusion that this is impossible to query with `EF`. I've implemented the [Azure DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient?view=azure-dotnet) and rewritten the query using the `SqlQuerySpec` to pass a parameterized SQL query, passing the cardNumber parameter and value, instead of doing this using LINQ.

The query I used was (some excessive brackets but I've added a couple of extra parameters that I cut from this example):

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE (IS_NULL(@cardNumber) = true OR EXISTS (SELECT VALUE card FROM card IN a.cards WHERE card.cardNumber LIKE @cardNumber))
```